# Best approach on creating a login screen on xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on an app where the user has to have an account. What I want to know is what would be the best approach to implement the Login and Register screens.

I can use Azure Active Directory B2C but as far I understand it, it uses the Microsoft's login UI, is it possible to customise this to match the apps overall design?

If not what other approaches would you recommend I take?

Currently, I am implementing the xamarin.iOS version but will also need the same approach on Xamarin.Android

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can provide and HTML template into which Azure AD will add the appropriate controls, allowing you to have quite a bit of control over the look and feel of the sign up and sign in pages.

This is documented in the aptly-titled article "Customize the Azure AD B2C user interface (UI)": https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization/